# Programa Pida Calificaciones y asigne una letra según la calificación obtenida (PYTHON)

Tags: python

Lo he estado intentando, pero al final no toma las variables valor y promedio para asignar una letra, según la calificación y el promedio obtenido. Realmente ya no sé cómo hacerlo, aún soy principiante y tengo que aprender mucho más. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

```
def sumar(valores):
    resultado = 0
    for valor in valores:
        resultado += valor
    return resultado
    
def restar(valores):    
    resultado = valores[0]
    for i in range(1,len(valores)):
        resultado -= valores[i]
    return resultado

#pedir numero de calificaciones
n = int(input("Número de calificaciones: "))

#lista donde se guardan los valores
listaElem = []

#guardar elementos
for i in range(0, n):
    valor = float(input("Ingresa calificaciones: "))
    #agregar elemento a la lista de valores
    listaElem.append(valor)
    
resultado = sumar(listaElem)
promedio = resultado / n
print(promedio)
    
if valor - promedio == "9.5 - 10":
    print("E")
elif valor - promedio == "9.0 - 9.4":
    print("Mb")
elif valor - promedio == "8.0 - 8.9":
    print("B")    
elif valor - promedio == "7.0 - 7.9":
    print("S")
elif valor - promedio == "<6.9":
    print("Na")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que dentro de tu condición de if no estás estableciendo realmente ningún rango numérico el cual le diga a tu programa a que rango de letra pertenece el promedio.

La forma correcta de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
def sumar(valores):
    resultado = 0
    for valor in valores:
        resultado += valor
    return resultado
    
def restar(valores):    
    resultado = valores[0]
    for i in range(1,len(valores)):
        resultado -= valores[i]
    return resultado

#pedir numero de calificaciones
n = int(input("Número de calificaciones: "))

#lista donde se guardan los valores
listaElem = []

#guardar elementos
for i in range(0, n):
    valor = float(input("Ingresa calificaciones: "))
    #agregar elemento a la lista de valores
    listaElem.append(valor)
    
resultado = sumar(listaElem)
promedio = resultado / n
print(promedio)

#para el último grado no es necesario asignar valores ya que por loǵica todo menor a 7.0 es reprobatoria en tu caso
if(promedio>=9.5):
    print("E")
elif(promedio>=9.0 and promedio<9.4):
    print("Mb")
elif(promedio>=8.0 and promedio<8.9):
    print("B")
elif(promedio>=7.0 and promedio<7.9):
    print("S")
else:
    print("Na")
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier pregunta no dudes en hacerla en los comentarios.